# Is it possible to tell the names of the $_GET variables the page is waiting for?

Tags: php

Hello I have a question about PHP $_POST and $_GET.

Let's say I have a web page that is expecting $_GET variables.

Are the variable names anonymous?

Let's say index.php has the script of

```
if( isset( $_GET['somevariale'] ) )
{
  rest of the code
}
```

Is it possible for anyone to find out the name of the $_GET variable the page is waiting for? Or would they have to play the guessing game?

Comment: why do you ask, you must always check user imputed data and not trust it is safe however it is added

Answer (score 0):

They'd have to play a guessing game if you didn't publish it or it couldn't be inferred from existing links on your site.

Of course, don't put it in `robots.txt` either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the PHP code without parsing it. So no you cant get it. But maybe save it somwhere else, i. E. a database?

Answer (score 0):

They can't see your index.php PHP code (let alone the variables) anyways unless they're opening the file directly.  They'll only see the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

That's simply impossible.
The only way they can find is if you server is not processing PHP properly and outputting it as is.

You can however protect your script in many ways like introducing passwords on scripts etc. but your source will have to know that password to use that script. Read more on HTTP auth, realms etc.

In you case however they will need to play a guessing game.